# How to unlink a file in node.js while there is an error on it?

Tags: node.js, stream, pipe, unlink

I have a .zip file, I want to extract it, but this file has a problem that it cannot be extracted. When that error is emitted, I want to delete(unlike) .zip file but I cannot do that. This is the code:

```
var unzipExtractor = unzip.Extract({ path: dir });
var source = fs.createReadStream(dir + 'sub.zip');
var unZip = source.pipe(unzipExtractor);
unZip.on('error', function(err) {
   fs.unlink(dir + 'sub.zip', function(err){
       if (err) console.log(err); else console.log('File extracted !');
   })
})
```

"File extracted !" is printed out, but the file sub.zip is not deleted.Can onyone help me out?
Thanks advance for any help!

Comment: I could suggest to `console.log(err)`

Comment: I did it, but the issue is still there @Michelem